# How to select all items from table excluding headers?

Tags: excel, vba, select

With this line you select all cells of table1, including headers:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Select
```

I need to select all objects save for the headers.

Answer (score 6):

1. You normally don't need to `Select`.
2. The [`DataBodyRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.ListObject.DataBodyRange) "represents the range of values, excluding the header row, in a table."

Use `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange`.